# (barssince condition) > close

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, trading, algorithmic-trading

I am trying to code the following..

(xyz condition that has happened within x last bars) is greater than close.

```
 counter = ta.barssince(x and y and z)
 within_bars = 600

 condition = counter <= within_bars
 trigger = condition > close
```

This is the error i am receiving..

"Cannot call 'operator >' with argument 'expr0'='condition'. An argument of 'series bool' type was used but a 'simple float' is expected."

How would i code this to work?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The error message is clear. You are comparing a `bool` with an `int` type.

Both `counter` and `within_bars` are of type `int`.

Then you have the following statement.

```
condition = counter <= within_bars
```

Here, the variable `condition` is of type `bool` because you are comparing two variables. The result is either `true` or `false`.

Then you are trying to compare `condition` with `close`. `close` is of type `float` and `condition` is `bool` as stated above.

It looks like you want to compare the price when your condition was `true` with the current `close` price. In that case, you can use the `ta.valuewhen()` function.

> Returns the value of the `source` series on the bar where the
> `condition` was true on the nth most recent occurrence.

Comment: Thanks for your answer sir. Im trying this... ta.valuewhen(condition, close, 0) but it is not the outcome i want. I would like the condition price within last 600 bars to be greater than the current close price.